# Eclipse Background Color of Title Bar

Tags: eclipse, themes

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu. I'm theming with the DevStyle plugin, using Dark Custom. The theme works really well, but there is just this big white bar on the top of the screen under the menu bar, that appears when I tile the editor top/ bottom  or left/right.

If have tried to theme the window in General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts and the editor tab, but there seems to be no option.

The maximize and minimize buttons from the side panel also have this annoying white background.

The bars look really ugly and out of place, and make me angry every time I look at them :-) .

Anyone has an idea of how to theme the background? Is it even possible?

[image]

```
________________________________
```

EDITED

It seems that there has been an improvement, probably due to updates. The white bar changed into two white squares in the corners.

This only happens with DevStyle.

I am on a Dell Laptop and using Ubuntu Budgie 19.04. I don't use any accessibility setting.

[image]

Comment: Hello Rainer, Sorry for the delay in replying to your question.

Do you still have this issue? I have never seen this issue in the past with DevStyle in Ubuntu.  In order to help you and anyone else who might be having this issue, can you respond to the following questions?

 - What architecture are you running on? 
 - Is there any accessibility setting you set in your system? (High contrast for example).
- Does this issue only happen with DevStyle? To check this you can switch to a different theme in Window > Preferences > Appearance.

Comment: Hi, @AaronIsaacLaraOtero , thanks for looking into this. Kindly see my edited question.

Comment: I just tried to replicate the issue by installing Eclipse 2019-06 for Java EE in Ubuntu budgie 19.04. It's a completely clean and basic installation and it looks good here (https://gyazo.com/c958cd3d81cce2159a017d68f0d4b372). It gotta be something else. Do you have any other outstanding plugin installed besides DevStyle? Or any Desktop Theme different to the default one?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The only plugin I have installed besides DevStyle is that from Codename One, but no theming plugin. I probably made some changes to my system that reflect in the styling, maybe something related to GTK3. The squares in the corner don't bother too much, though, so I keep using DevStyle normally. Great plugin...